# Which book should I start to know good understanding of light-matter interaction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics

Please suggest to me *one or two books*. And  also if there is anything else interesting to follow (lectures or lecture notes).

Comment: Please read the banner, everyone. "Answers containing only a reference to a book or paper will be removed!"

Answer (score 2):

I have heard the term "light-matter interaction" more frequently in a non-relativistic context so that is what I address here.

There are many good references on the market. I few that I have used and seen recommended elsewhere are:

- G. Grynberg, A. Aspect, and C. Fabre, Introduction to Quantum Optics: From the Semi‐classical approach to Quantized Light.

The main prerequisites are basic notions on electromagnetism and quantum mechanics. It first introduces light-matter interaction following a semiclassical approach and then it goes on with the fully quantized version. The quantization of light is done in a comprehensive way; however, it is not the most formal reference in this regard. This book includes a couple of chapters dedicated to laser theory and non-linear optics as more "advanced topics", that make contact with current research. It is very complete and is loaded with complements at the end of each chapter.

- C. Cohen-Tannoudji, J. Dupont-Roc, and G. Grynberg, Photons and Atoms: Introduction to Quantum Electrodynamics.

This one is a favourite of mine, although a bit more advanced. The first 150 pages or so are dedicated to classical electrodynamics and many of its subtleties, as well as going over the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian approach. This first part is naturally followed by quantum electrodynamics in the Coulomb gauge and other equivalent, non-covariant formulations. It ends with the covariant formulation. This book is also full of complements at the end of each chapter and solved exercises.

Photons and atoms is as complete as it gets in the treatment of quantum electrodynamics, but it may be overkill for a first reference.

- D. A. Steck, Quantum and Atom Optics [http://atomoptics-nas.uoregon.edu/~dsteck/teaching/quantum-optics/]

I have not really used this one but I have been told it is  very complete. You can see from its table of contents that it covers a very wide range of topics. From the semi-classical approach to a fully quantum description (which starts on page 400), and then it goes on to stochastic methods (which I have not seen in any of the other recommendations) and a final part on numerical methods. It even includes path integral formalism discussions and path integral calculations of Casimir energies. It looks like anything you can think of in this field can be found in the teaching notes by Steck.

I am sure there are many more references, this is not an exhaustive list, but this should be more than enough to get started with non-relativistic light-matter interaction. For the sake of completeness, I will mention a few QFT references that treat relativistic Quantum Electrodynamics, the most "fundamental" theory we currently have to describe the interaction between charged particles and photons:

- M. Maggiore, A modern introduction to Quantum Field Theory.

This one has all the usual field theory, but I particularly enjoyed the chapter dedicated to the quantization of free fields and, in particular, the section dedicated to the electromagnetic field. It has a nice way to explain the connection between different gauges.

- M. Srednicki, Quantum Field Theory.
- M. E. Peskin, D. V. Schroeder, An introduction to Quantum Field Theory.

I have used both these books and they are very complete and full of examples, which is helpful with a complicated topic as QFT is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a free course about "atom-light interaction" online:https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-421-atomic-and-optical-physics-i-spring-2014/

The teacher is Prof. Ketterle who win the Noble price in 2001. I strongly recommend his course!